# How to create paginated table from MySQL database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, pagination

I'm about to start work on a new project and wanted some advice before beginning.

I have a MySQL table that I need to display on my website.  The table has over 100 million lines in it.  The table has 2 columns in it:  `domainid` and `domainname`.

The `domainid` column is simply numbers starting at 1 and going up to over 100 million.  In the `domainname` table I have a list of domains such as this:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
test6
```

**Basically what I'm trying to do is this:**

I want to display 1000 domains per page on my website - in a table.  The table would be 4 columns and 250 lines.  To start with, I'm not sure exactly how to get data from the database and actually display it in my HTML table.  I know it can be done with PHP of course, just not sure how.

The second thing I need to add is some sort of pagination.  It doesn't need to be pretty, I just need a way to have pages auto generated at the bottom of the list so that people can go from one page to the next and view 1000 records on each page - obviously I wouldn't want all 100 million records displayed on a single page.

**So here's the problem I'm having:**  I'm not sure how to get the MySQL data and display it on my website quickly - I don't want it taking forever to load the pages just because the database is large.  And second I really need a way to add pagination to the table.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.  I'm not sure how difficult doing this is going to be, but any assistance you can provide would be great.

Comment: Have you ever tried using a PHP framework like CodeIgniter? It has a built in pagination. Here's the link, it might give you an idea http://ellislab.com/codeigniter

Comment: I think you should start by learning basics from google. You can even find pre written stuff if you search well enough. This isn't a place for question like this.

Comment: There's a ton of ways to do what I'm asking.  The reason I'm asking here is because I'd like to know what the best way to do it is.

Comment: I don't think you should be focusing on best way. First at least get a "way" then come here with that "way" and ask how to optimize it or fix it. I suggest you to take some tutorials on fetching data from mysql first.

Comment: @user2970202: Check out the answer . this is the best way to create a different file with a function and defin start page and end page so result shows according to the requirement

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the total number of rows

```
Select count(*) from yourtable
```

Then to display a page, do some whizzy maths like this

```
$rows_per_page = 1000;
$page_no = 2;  // hint, start counting pages at page 0, it will make things easier
$offset = $page_no * $rows_per_page;

// 0 = offset (where to start)
// 1000 = number of rows returned
select * from yourtable limit $offset,$rows_per_page
```

Because you have so many rows, I would use an html select to choose which page you want to go to, or just have a next and previous button and leave it like that

To figure out how many page there are, you need some more maths

```
$total_rows = 100000000;
$rows_per_page = 1000;
$num_pages = $total_rows / $rows_per_page;
```

Answer (score 1):

***USE THIS CODE :***
   Create pages config,paginate,index in php.

- Here Paginate page creates design for format(prev and next button to scroll page).
- Config create connection with database.
- index page firstly define the variable for create number of result per page, page number , total result etc
- index page(design) defines the how page show ,which can be modify by you according to you priority to show page design.

**CONFIG.PHP**

```
$mysql_hostname = "host"; 
$mysql_user = "usr";            
$mysql_password = "pass";           
$mysql_database = "db"; 

$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Error on database connection");
```

**PAGINATE.PHP**

```
function paginate($reload, $page, $tpages) {
$adjacents = 2;
$prevlabel = "&lsaquo; Prev";
$nextlabel = "Next &rsaquo;";
$out = "";
// previous
if ($page == 1) {
    $out.= "<span>".$prevlabel."</span>\n";
} elseif ($page == 2) {
    $out.="<li><a href=\"".$reload."\">".$prevlabel."</a>\n</li>";
} else {
    $out.="<li><a href=\"".$reload."&amp;page=".($page - 1)."\">".$prevlabel."</a>\n</li>";
}
$pmin=($page>$adjacents)?($page - $adjacents):1;
$pmax=($page<($tpages - $adjacents))?($page + $adjacents):$tpages;
for ($i = $pmin; $i <= $pmax; $i++) {
    if ($i == $page) {
        $out.= "<li class=\"active\"><a href=''>".$i."</a></li>\n";
    } elseif ($i == 1) {
        $out.= "<li><a href=\"".$reload."\">".$i."</a>\n</li>";
    } else {
        $out.= "<li><a href=\"".$reload. "&amp;page=".$i."\">".$i. "</a>\n</li>";
    }
}

if ($page<($tpages - $adjacents)) {
    $out.= "<a style='font-size:11px' href=\"" . $reload."&amp;page=".$tpages."\">" .$tpages."</a>\n";
}
// next
if ($page < $tpages) {
    $out.= "<li><a href=\"".$reload."&amp;page=".($page + 1)."\">".$nextlabel."</a>\n</li>";
} else {
    $out.= "<span style='font-size:11px'>".$nextlabel."</span>\n";
}
$out.= "";
return $out;
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
include('config.php');    //include of db config file
include ('paginate.php'); //include of paginat page

$per_page = 1000;         // number of results to show per page

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE");

$total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);//total pages we going to have
//-------------if page is setcheck------------------//
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
$show_page = $_GET['page']; //current page
if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages) {
    $start = ($show_page - 1) * $per_page;
    $end = $start + $per_page;
} else {
    // error - show first set of results
    $start = 0;              
    $end = $per_page;
}
} else {
// if page isn't set, show first set of results
$start = 0;
$end = $per_page;
}
// display pagination
$page = intval($_GET['page']);
$tpages=$total_pages;
if ($page <= 0)
$page = 1;

?>
```

**// DESIGNING and displaying data(code continuing in index.php)**

```
<?php
$reload = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?tpages=" . $tpages;
echo '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
if ($total_pages > 1) {
    echo paginate($reload, $show_page, $total_pages);
}
echo "</ul></div>";
// display data in table
echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
echo "<thead><tr><th>DOMAIN CODE</th> <th>DOMAIN Name</th></tr></thead>";
// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
    // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
    if ($i == $total_results) {
        break;
    }
    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr " . $cls . ">";
    echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'domainid') . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'domainname') . '</td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}       
// close table>
echo "</table>";
// pagination
?>
```